# libcurl parsing response headers and storing as key-value pairs c++

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am using libcurl for network communication, So far I am able to read the response data and read it in memory/file. Now I am trying to parse the response headers and put them as key value pair,

I am able to partially parse some data but there appears to be some corruption/junk data
Here is my current code

```
#include "iostream"
#include "curl/curl.h"
#include "cstring"


typedef struct internal_cfile_data{
  char *data;
  int size;
} icfd;

class CFile{
public:
  bool CURLCreate(const char* strURL);
  bool CURLAddOptionProtocol(CURLoption opt,void* value);
  bool CURLAddOptionHeader(const char* key,const char* value);
  bool CURLAddOption(const char* name, const char* value);
  bool CURLOpen();
  size_t Read(void* pointer, size_t size);
  void Close();
  static size_t internal_header_read(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nitems, void *userdata)
  {
    size_t realsize = size * nitems;
    icfd *mem = (icfd*) userdata;
    char *ptr = (char *)realloc(mem->data,mem->size+realsize);

    if(!ptr) {
      /* out of memory */
      printf("not enough memory (realloc() returned NULL)\n");
      return 0;
    }
    mem->data = ptr;
    memcpy(&(mem->data[mem->size]), buffer, realsize);
    //try to parse
    std::string del = ":";
    std::string tmp(&mem->data[mem->size]);
    if(tmp.find(del)){ 
            std::string token = tmp.substr(0, tmp.find(del));
            std::cout<<"Key:::"<<token<<"--->"<<tmp.erase(0, token.length()+del.length())<<std::endl;
    }
    mem->size += realsize;
    return realsize;
  }
public:
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

protected:
  icfd internal_data;
  icfd internal_headers;
  struct curl_slist *header_list = NULL;
  size_t internal_file_read_index = 0;
};

/*******************************************************
 * CFile implementation
 *******************************************************/

bool CFile::CURLCreate(const char* strURL)
{
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if (curl)
  {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, strURL);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

bool CFile::CURLOpen()
{
  internal_data.data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(icfd));
  internal_headers.data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(icfd));
  internal_headers.size = 0;
  internal_data.size = 0;
  /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, internal_read);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &internal_data);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, internal_header_read);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, &internal_headers);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header_list);
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  /* Check for errors */
  if(res != CURLE_OK){
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
void CFile::Close()
{
  /* always cleanup */
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  curl_global_cleanup();
  curl_slist_free_all(header_list);
}

int main()
{
        CFile file;
        file.CURLCreate("http://google.com/");
        file.CURLOpen();
        file.Close();
        return 0;
}
```

Output of this code is something like

```
* Expire in 50 ms for 1 (transfer 0x561f163d16b0)
*   Trying 172.217.163.206...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 149948 ms for 3 (transfer 0x561f163d16b0)
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x561f163d16b0)
* Connected to google.com (172.217.163.206) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Key:::HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
m��n--->
< Location: http://www.google.com/
Key:::Location---> http://www.google.com/

< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Key:::Content-Type---> text/html; charset=UTF-8

< Date: Sun, 11 Oct 2020 13:50:54 GMT
Key:::Date---> Sun, 11 Oct 2020 13:50:54 GMT

< Expires: Tue, 10 Nov 2020 13:50:54 GMT
Key:::Expires---> Tue, 10 Nov 2020 13:50:54 GMT

< Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Key:::Cache-Control---> public, max-age=2592000

< Server: gws
Key:::Server---> gws

< Content-Length: 219
Key:::Content-Length---> 219
��W_
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
Key:::X-XSS-Protection---> 0

< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Key:::X-Frame-Options---> SAMEORIGIN

Key:::
--->
< 
* Connection #0 to host google.com left intact
```

How can I parse the http response headers and store them as key value pair in memory

Comment: Perhaps by attempting to write C++ code instead of C? All of that work to define `internal_cfile_data` is attempting to reinvent a wheel called `std::string`. In C++ we have this class that's perfectly designed to handle text of arbitrary length. Instead of struggling to `malloc`/`realloc`, trying to correctly `memcpy` everything, because if it's not 100% perfect you will end up trying to chase down mysterious bugs -- why not simply use `std::string` to capture this data, and let C++ do everything for you, guaranteed to be 100% correct?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thank you. I have moved to use `std::string` and `std::map`